# Laptop as External Screen

Tags: laptop, external-display

I've the following laptop: Samsung 700G7C and I want to use it as external monitor for my DELL Server, wonder if it's possible at all and if so what do I need to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your laptop can do VGA capture, then no not directly.

There are work arounds though. If you need eyes in, when it is working, then Remote Desktop can be used to RDP in.

Otherwise, another great solution is to get an IP KVM, such as the Lantronix Spider. You can put the video from the server to the KVM, and then type the IP of the KVM into your browser from any machine with Java installed (LDAP or Username / pw combinations available). This will give you BIOS level remote control for just about anything, and you don't have to be in the closet to image a server, adjust the BIOS or whatever you might be doing that you need hands on because the OS is not configured for remote access.

Comment: My problem is - it's gonna be a blank PC initially - I need to install Windows Server on it - not sure if I'll get away with just grabbing the video. Could you confirm? How do I check for the VGA capture existance - it's a fairly advanced gaming laptop, can it get it just by looking at the sockets?

Comment: No, it would not. You will need some form of keyboard mouse along with the video. The IP KVM would work, as would the more traditional pullout monitor. http://www.rackmountsolutions.net/Rackmount_Keyboard_LCD_Entry.asp